# Print a ListView from my C# Web App

Tags: c#

Im building out a c# web app here and I have a Listview. I would like to have a button on the page that when clicked it will print the listview easily. Anyone have any idea how this would be done?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: you can redirect to a page with order id as url parameter and in that page add a repeater that shows data for this order on `page_load` and add this to your body tag - `window.print();`

Comment: What have you coded so far? Did you make some research? This seems to be asking other people to do your job, and I don't think that's your intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Adding the following code inside the button click event. Hope fully it will help.

```
    this.ListView1.DataBind();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    ListView1.RenderControl(hw);
    string ListViewHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
    sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
    sb.Append("var printList = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
    sb.Append(",top=0,width=800,height=700,status=0');");
    sb.Append("printList.document.write(\"");
    sb.Append(ListViewHTML);
    sb.Append("\");");
    sb.Append("printList.document.close();");
    sb.Append("printList.focus();");
    sb.Append("printList.print();");
    sb.Append("printList.close();};");
    sb.Append("</script>");
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ListViewPrint", sb.ToString());
    this.ListView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options that I can think of:

1. Send this to a different page with an ID (perhaps the order number?) in the query string; read the order id from the query string, and output the details in the page. Then call `window.print` on `window.load`

Something like:

```
Order o = DAL.GetOrderByID(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["OrderID"]));
//output the order in this new page...
```

On this new page, have a line like this:

```
window.onload=function(){window.print();};
```

1. Use this [jquery plugin](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm) to do it. It creates a frame in the page and calls `.print` on the frame. Seems very simple to implement.

Comment: I believe the jquery function will work here in this situation, Ill give it a go. thanks for the advice.